# dash callback with large number of outputs takes a long time to load

Tags: css, caching, plotly-dash

I have a dash callback that has a large number of outputs:

```
@app.callback(
    barcodeOutputs,
    Input('json_output', 'children'),
    [State('manufacturer_id_dropdown', 'value'), State('session_store', 'data')],
)
def update(json_arr, mfgId, session_store):
```

the output list, barcodeOutputs, has a length of 900.  when I run the dash app with the large number of outputs, the app takes a long time to load.  the outputs are to update a list of html style elements, because I want to use the color style to highlight an html element if there is an error for that field.  however, I have to add all the styles of the html elements to the output array.

is there a way to make the app faster?  I read about caching in dash but I'm not sure if it will work in this case.  I also read something about loading the css separately.